# A question on Gaussian small ball probability

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Consider the random variable $$ G = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \lambda_j Z_j^2 $$
where $Z_j \sim_{\substack{i.i.d}} N(0,1)$ and $\lambda_j$ some non increasing sequence of positive numbers with $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \lambda_j < \infty$.

A number of authors (for example in this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-25/issue-1/On-the-lower-tail-probabilities-of-some-random-series/10.1214/aop/1024404294.full)) have quantified the small ball probability $$ \mathbb{P}(G \leq \epsilon) \; \; \; \text{as} \; \; \; \epsilon \downarrow 0 $$ in terms of the decay rate of the coefficients $\lambda_j$.

Consider now the truncated sum $G_{L_n} = \sum_{j=1}^{L_n} \lambda_j Z_j^2 $. In the special case where $\lambda_j = j^{-\alpha}$ for some $\alpha > 1$, I am looking for a reference that quantifies the small ball probability of $G_{L_n}$ as $L_n \uparrow \infty$ and $\epsilon = \epsilon_n \downarrow 0$. In particular, how does $$ \mathbb{P}(G_{L_n} \leq \epsilon_n)\qquad\qquad\qquad (1)$$
behave as a function of the sequences $\{L_n , \epsilon_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$
. As is expected, there will typically be several regimes depending on how fast $L_n$ and $\epsilon_n^{-1}$ grow relative to each other and the sequence $\{\lambda_j \}_{j=1}^{\infty}$.

Is a discussion of the behavior of $(1)$ written down somewhere?